# Share controller property to model method - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a question - is it possible to pass or share property from controller to model in laravel. Here is some code example of "problem".

Basically I have a model method which is getting product price in given currency.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function getPrice()
        {
            return number_format($this->price_retail / $this->sessionHelper->getCurrentCurrency()->conversion_rate, 2);
        }
}
```

sessionHelper is separate class which is providing  information about current currency. I would like to remove this part and use property from controller

In project my productController has access to global variables extended from baseController:

```
class ProductController extends BaseController
{
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->currentCurrency  //gives current currency info which i need in model
    }
   //test function
   public function showFirstProductPrice(){
       $this->product->first()->getPrice();
   }
}
```

I could do something like passing variable through function like this:

```
$this->product->first()->getPrice($Variable);
```

But in view every time i will need to pass $variable. Currently I call model method directly which is calling helper for currency conversion rate and it's working but I guess there is better way to do that.

Have somebody any ideas?

Comment: for get price on `function getPrice()` need pass object and call `function`

Comment: There are `appends`, read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) section.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can pass a variable.

```
    class Product extends Model
   {
    public function getPrice($variable)
        {
            return number_format($this->price_retail /$variable, 2);
        }
    }
```

in your controller you can do this

```
    class ProductController extends BaseController
{
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->currentCurrency  //gives current currency info which i need in model
    }
   //test function
   public function showFirstProductPrice(){
       $this->product->first()->getPrice($variable);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes but every time i will call this function  $variable must be passed. So if i take $products = $this->product->limit(30)->get() and send it to view i will need also send $conversion_rate variable  because i will need to foreach products and call getPrice on each one like this  $product->getPrice($conversion_rate). I am looking for some clean solution where i wont need extra variable passing to view.